# Problems installing pip and scipy on window 8, python3.5.1 64 bit

Tags: python, cmd, scipy, pip, installation

> C:\Users\LakhanS>pip install scipy
>       Collecting scipy
>         Using cached scipy-0.19.0.zip
>       Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
>         Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... error
>         Complete output from command c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\py
>       thon35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\Lakhan
>       S\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\scipy\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize
>       , 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(com
>       pile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Tem
>       p\tmpe52okcwapip-wheel- --python-tag cp35:
>         lapack_opt_info:
>         openblas_lapack_info:
>           libraries openblas not found in ['c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\progra
>       ms\python\python35\lib', 'C:\', 'c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\program
>       s\python\python35\libs']
>           NOT AVAILABLE

```
  lapack_mkl_info:
    libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\programs
\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\programs\
\python\\python35\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nump
y\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-wh
eels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
    warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_3_10_info:
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_threads_info:
  Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  atlas_info:
  <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
    NOT AVAILABLE

  c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nump
y\distutils\system_info.py:1532: UserWarning:
      Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
      the ATLAS environment variable.
    warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
  lapack_info:
    libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\programs
\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\programs\
\python\\python35\\libs']
    NOT AVAILABLE

  c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nump
y\distutils\system_info.py:1543: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
      Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
      the LAPACK environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
  lapack_src_info:
    NOT AVAILABLE

  c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nump
y\distutils\system_info.py:1546: UserWarning:
      Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
      Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
      numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
      the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
    warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
    NOT AVAILABLE

  Running from scipy source directory.
  non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\scipy\setup.py"
, line 416, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\scipy\setup.py"
, line 412, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\scipy\setup.py"
, line 336, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('scipy')
    File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1000, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 969, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py

      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage('linalg')
    File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1000, in add_subpackage
      caller_level = 2)
    File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 969, in get_subpackage
      caller_level = caller_level + 1)
    File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packa
ges\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py

      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
      raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
  numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  Complete output from command c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\py
thon35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Lakhan
S\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize
, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(com
pile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).


  ----------------------------------------
  Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\
python35\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Lakh
anS\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokeni
ze, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(c
ompile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-ed1va6j1-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
 --compile:

    Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
    with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:

      - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
                               release)
      - `pip install scipy`   (last SciPy release on PyPI)


    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\prog
rams\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\progr
ams\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\progra
ms\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\program
s\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nu
mpy\distutils\system_info.py:639: UserWarning: Specified path C:\projects\numpy-
wheels\windows-wheel-builder\atlas-builds\atlas-3.11.38-sse2-64\lib is invalid.
      warnings.warn('Specified path %s is invalid.' % d)
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nu
mpy\distutils\system_info.py:1532: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\progra
ms\\python\\python35\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\lakhans\\appdata\\local\\program
s\\python\\python35\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nu
mpy\distutils\system_info.py:1543: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\nu
mpy\distutils\system_info.py:1546: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    Running from scipy source directory.
    non-existing path in 'scipy\\integrate': 'quadpack.h'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\scipy\setup.p
y", line 416, in <module>
        setup_package()
      File "C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\scipy\setup.p
y", line 412, in setup_package
        setup(**metadata)
      File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
        config = configuration()
      File "C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\scipy\setup.p
y", line 336, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('scipy')
      File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1000, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 969, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_
py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\setup.py", line 15, in configuration
        config.add_subpackage('linalg')
      File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1000, in add_subpackage
        caller_level = 2)
      File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 969, in get_subpackage
        caller_level = caller_level + 1)
      File "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-pac
kages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 906, in _get_configuration_from_setup_
py
        config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
      File "scipy\linalg\setup.py", line 20, in configuration
        raise NotFoundError('no lapack/blas resources found')
    numpy.distutils.system_info.NotFoundError: no lapack/blas resources found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\lakhans\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\python.exe -u -
c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\LakhanS\\AppData\\Local\\Tem
p\\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file
__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '
exec'))" install --record C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-ed1va6j1-recor
d\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with
error code 1 in C:\Users\LakhanS\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-mkzc0d6e\scipy\

C:\Users\LakhanS>^A
'☺' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\LakhanS>
```

Answer (score 0):

visit http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

download the file scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl

save it at C:\Python35\Scripts

use the following script to install:

```
cd C:\Python35\Scripts

pip install "scipy‑0.19.0‑cp35‑cp35m‑win_amd64.whl"
```

Comment: @LakhanPahuja Is there any message or tip when error occurs?

Comment: DID NOT FIND THE ANSWERS  ANYWAY THANKS, BUT I INSTALL ANACONDA PROBLEM SOLVED

Comment: Will that work on an intel processor?
If not, what do you do for 64-bit intel?